# JSP IllegalStateException и JasperException

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Пишу crud приложение по примерам из открытых источников. При открытии моего единственного jsp файла. Вероятно, ошибка кроется где-то в контроллере или конфигурационных файлах, но самостоятельно выявить не смог
Код ошибки:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/person.jsp] at line [39]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/person.jsp] at line [39]

36:         </c:if>
37:         <tr>
38:             <td>
39:                 <form:label path="name">
40:                     <spring:message text="Name"/>
41:                 </form:label>
42:             </td>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'person' available as request attribute
```

person.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Person Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ccc;}
        .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}
        .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#f0f0f0;}
        .tg .tg-4eph{background-color:#f9f9f9}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Add a Person
</h1>

<c:url var="addAction" value="/person/add" >

<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="name">
                    <spring:message text="Name"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="country">
                    <spring:message text="Country"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="country" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Person"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty person.name}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Person"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</c:url>
<br>
<h3>Persons List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listPersons}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">Person ID</th>
            <th width="120">Person Name</th>
            <th width="120">Person Country</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listPersons}" var="person">
            <tr>
                <td>${person.id}</td>
                <td>${person.name}</td>
                <td>${person.country}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${person.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${person.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

**PersonController.java**:

```
package com.ma3stro.crudperson.controller;

import com.ma3stro.crudperson.model.Person;
import com.ma3stro.crudperson.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService service;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    public void setService(PersonService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", service.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

    //add and update
    @RequestMapping(value = "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p) {
        if(p.getId() == 0)
            service.addPerson(p);
        else
            service.updatePerson(p);
        return "redirect:/persons";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        service.removePerson(id);
        return "redirect:/persons";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", service.getPersonById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", service.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/person" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.ma3stro.crudperson.model.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.ma3stro.crudperson.repository.PersonRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <!--<beans:bean id="personService" class="com.ma3stro.crudperson.service.PersonServiceImpl">-->
        <!--<beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>-->
    <!--</beans:bean>-->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ma3stro.crudperson.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ma3stro.crudperson.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ma3stro.crudperson.service" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

На всякий случай прикреплю [структуру проекта](http://prntscr.com/hzj6hp)

Comment: Вы бы укоротили код и выделили бы самое важное, то думаю мало кто захочет в такой портянке разбираться